# Rfcomm0 Console Over Bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, terminal

I followed this tutorial here: http://jasiek.me/2014/10/04/bluetooth-console-on-a-raspberry-pi-using-a-usb-adapter.html

I am trying to connect my Galaxy Note 5 to my Pi over a USB Bluetoothub module. When I use the command `sudo bluetooth-agent 1234` my phone asks for a pin number, I type 1234 and everything is great. But when I want to pair the devices for Rfcomm0 with the command `sudo rfcomm watch /dev/rfcomm0 3 /sbin/agetty rfcomm0 linux 115200` my phone asks for a pin number again, and no matter what four numbers I type in it always rejects the connection.

How can I use a Bluetooth console with my phone?

Comment: It probably hasn't paired properly (`bluetooth-agent 1234` should pair it, `sudo rfcomm watch` probably waits for a serial connection from the phone on the connected bluetooth (via [BlueTerm](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=es.pymasde.blueterm) or similar)) - make sure that sdptool command worked first though. [This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92255/how-do-i-connect-and-send-data-to-a-bluetooth-serial-port-on-linux) post on U&L may help. Also, what bluetooth adapter are you using (look at `lsusb`, `hcitool` etc - not all bluetooth devices work well)

Comment: @Wilf Am I forwarding the right port with sdptool, cause I've seen other people use port 22. Also I am using the same adapter that I have seen many, many people use with Rfcomm0.

Comment: Ok, I have a new problem, it is in the edited question.